# neo4j how to know each node along the BFS

Tags: neo4j, breadth-first-search

everyone
I have a question here with neo4j. Right now I learn the [traversal example](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html).

```
 for ( Path position : db.traversalDescription()
            .breadthFirst()
            .relationships( Rels.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING )           
            .traverse( node ) )
    {
        output += position + "\n";
    }
```

But they print out the entire path from node"Ed"

2-->0-->5-->4-->1

if i have a large and complex graph data set. maybe from node 5 to node 4, during other node BFS I already traversed. So this time, I can stop at node 5.
So question here is that, i want to know each node along the bfs and make some little test of own and then decide whether keep traversing or not.
How to deal with this?

Comment: Use `Evaluator`, your own implementation or some of [the common ones](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/2.0.2/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/Evaluators.html). Or just break the loop if `Path position` matches your criteria.

Comment: Also, click the `help` button at the top of your screen, take the tour, and read through the help center pages for StackOverflow. Then go back and fix grammar, formatting and content of your questions until they are understandable and to the point; don't post duplicates; and accept the responses that answer your questions.

Comment: thanks. but how to get the currently node on the path(position in this code)?

Comment: Have you tried `Path#endNode()`? In your case `position.endNode()`. See [apidocs](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/2.0.2/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html#endNode%28%29)